# How to sort response by coinmarketcap api v1 by price in usd?

Tags: php, arrays, api

I am using coinmarketcap api to get top 100 cyptocurrencies. By default, the response is sorted by rank, but i want the response to be sorted by **price**.

**I want to display them sorted by price in descending order.**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'), true);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value["id"];
    $name = $value["name"];
    $price_usd = $value["price_usd"];
    $percent_change_24h = $value['percent_change_24h'];
    $percent_change_7d = $value['percent_change_7d'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $id . "<span>" . $name . "/ USD</span></td>";
    echo "<td>". $price_usd ."</td>";
    echo "<td><i class = 'fa fa-caret-up' aria-hidden = 'true'>". $percent_change_24h . "<span> " . $percent_change_7d . "</span></i></td>";
    echo    "</tr>";  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [array-multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)? you can do it like:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'), true);
array_multisort(array_column($data, "price_usd"), SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Or you can change `price_usd` to any field you need and nop `$data` will be sorted form highest to lowest and you can run your `for-loop` on it